# Does getblockcount return the correct block count when running in prune mode?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I am currently running a bitcoin node with prune=550.

The getBlockCount from `$ bitcoin-cli getblockcount` does not match `https://blockexplorer.com/api/status?q=getBlockCount`.  As I understand it, the bitcoind is still syncing the node since the bitcoin-cli getblockcount is rising at a steady pace.

Will the getblockcount from a node running with prune=550 eventually match the official getblockcount?

Comment: Yes, because bitcoin-core must be rescan the network to build the actual status of blockchain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will match. `getblockcount` is the number of blocks that you have already synced to, regardless of pruning.